# Magento XML layout with custom modules

Tags: xml, layout, templates, magento

I'm trying to include a custom template into the checkout process on the shipping page.  I want that template to adopt the functionality of its parent template so I can use any of the shipping variables within the template.  However I can't get magento to load the template.  Here is my XML (the header scripts are adding successfully).  My module is called Tm_ShippingDate

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

<checkout_multishipping_shipping>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-blue.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/lang/calendar-en.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    </reference>

    <block type="tm/multishipping_shipping" name="tm_shippingdate" template="tm/shippingdate/shippingdate.phtml"></block>

    <!-- <block type="checkout/multishipping_shipping" name="checkout_shipping" template="checkout/multishipping/shippingdate.phtml"> -->
</checkout_multishipping_shipping>
```

I then have this in my checkout shipping.phtml template

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('shippingdate') ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
<reference name="checkout_shipping">
<block type="tm/multishipping_shipping" name="shippingdate" template="tm/shippingdate/shippingdate.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

Then in your shipping.phtml:

```
$this->getChildHtml('shippingdate');
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, have you tried changing to

```
<block type="tm/multishipping_shipping" name="shippingdate" template="tm/shippingdate/shippingdate.phtml"></block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the Block in the Module code?